# Chrome/Opera Anchor Link Issue on Squarespace Site

Tags: google-chrome, hyperlink, anchor, squarespace

**ISSUE**

Anchor links on an existing Squarespace website have ceased working:

[LINK](https://garchitects.ca)

The webpage works as designed in both Firefox and IE, but the navigation links do not work in Chrome (v61.0.3163.100) or Opera (v48.0.2685.35) since updating to the latest versions. In Chrome or Opera, the link flashes the intended destination but won't jump to that location.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

Squarespace organizes each content section in the site roughly like so:

```
<div class="parallax-item" data-url-id="contact" id="yui_123456789">
    <div class="title-desc-wrapper over-image no-main-image">
        <div class="title-desc-inner" data-collection-id="3456789012">
            <div class="page-title-wrapper" id="yui_234567890">
                <h1 class="page-title">Contact</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

The fact that this is a Squarespace site complicates the issue. The target of the anchor (for example /#contact) is not a div with that unique id, but rather an html attribute 'data-url-id="contact"'. The div id is an auto-generated unique identifier (these start with 'yui_').

If I insert a code-block manually in Squarespace and add a "`<div id='contact'></div>`" the link will fire properly in Chrome and will jump (without animation) to that spot. Unfortunately I cannot use Squarespace tools to insert that div in the proper place in the page or add animation.

If I try to use jQuery to 'append' or 'prepend' the same "`<div id='contact'></div>`" into the page in the proper spot (directly inside the parent div), the anchor link will not work, which leads me to believe that there is some Squarespace javascript running interference?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you contacted Squarespace support..?

Comment: @jfox they won't touch it because I have developer tools enabled. They could reproduce the issue but said that these browser versions are too new for them to have figured out all the bugs yet.

Answer (score 0):

@TheNally I see what you mean now, okay so I just did a quick test and the jQuery append div works as expected – anchor without any animations – but you're currently appending multiple instances of them right now so it doesn't know where to point to.

I would suggest adding an id to each section `.title-desc-wrapper` then include [Smooth Scroll](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) snippet to animate. Relatively minor additions that should hold you over until the bug has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I'll try that.